# getline doesn't store the string in the variable

Tags: c, string, getline

I wrote a function that opens a file which name is given by the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getfile(FILE** pfile)  
{
    void getrep(char*,char,char);
    void clear(void);
    char rep;
    char* nfile=NULL;
    printf("Name of the file: ");
    clear();
    nfile=NULL;
    getline(&nfile,NULL,stdin);
    printf("The name of the file is: %s\n",nfile);
    *pfile=fopen(nfile,"r");
    while(!*pfile)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file. Want to retry <Y/N> ? ");
        getrep(&rep,'Y','N');
        if(rep=='Y')
        {
            system("clear");
            free(nfile);
            nfile=NULL;
            printf("Name of the file: ");
            clear();
            getline(&nfile,NULL,stdin);
            printf("The name of the file is: %s\n",nfile);
            *pfile=fopen(nfile,"r");
        }
        else
            exit(-1);
    }
    free(nfile);
}
```

The getrep function simply ensures that the user gives Y or N or y or n as an answer. Here's the clear function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clear(void)
{
    char c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n');
}
```

Here's what I get when I run the program:

> Name of the file: Data.dat
>
> The name of the file is: (null)
>
> Can't open the file. Want to retry  ?

When I used the debugger gdb and printed the value of nfile after entering the file's name, it remains 0x0, i.e, NULL. (You might have noticed that I allocated no memory for nfile, but I initialized this variable to NULL so that getline will do it for me. I'm using getline instead of gets because it seems better and, after all, ubuntu 16.04 hates gets)

I believe the reason why this is happening is that when the user is asked to enter the name, it's due to the getchar() in the clear function. Thus the name entered by the user is erased, and the nfile receives nothing in getline. I also tried using this clear function instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clear2(void)
{
    char c;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n');
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the same result. I used `fflush(stdin);` instead of `clear();` but this time the program skips getline not letting the user enter anything. I also removed the space that comes after file: in `printf("Name of the file: ");` but nothing changes.

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not declare functions inside another function. It can lead to confusion and you would have to do it in every function that would call them.

Comment: @iharob Thank you very much. Indeed you're right that's something to be avoided and we should use headers instead. However, getfile, getrep and clear are functions of the same personal "library", that's why I'm not doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the `getline` manual page`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

> If `*lineptr` is set to NULL and `*n` is set `0` before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line

Since you pass a `NULL` pointers as the `n` argument, the call will not allocate a buffer for you. You need to explicitly pass a pointer to a variable of `size_t` that has been initialized to zero:

```
char *nfile = NULL;
size_t n = 0;
getline(&nfile,&n,stdin);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My bad I didn't read correctly how to use getline. I'm going to rectify my program now and test it.

Comment: You're right. getline is working now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in the `getline` call.

The second parameter passed in is `NULL` which is incorrect.

Rather it should be like this:

```
size_t n = 0;
getline(&nfile,&n,stdin);
```

As per the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) for `getline`, states:

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then
>   getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
>   should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

Comment: `getline(&nfile,0,stdin);` and `getline(&nfile,NULL,stdin);` are the same here.

Comment: I will refrain from getting into the nuances of the NULL vs 0 which is not the same! ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. My bad I didn't read correctly how to use getline. I'm going to rectify my program now and test it.

Comment: You're right. getline is working now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @t0mm13b The keyword was "here". Regardless, your answer when I posted my comment was not correct.